# Where can I put my SQLite database in my QT application if I can't put it in my resources?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt, resources

Recently I was trying to put a SQLite database into a QT 5 application I'm writing.  I want it to be universally accessible - that is on all systems regardless of where it's installed.  I put it as a resource then found out that evidently you can't put databases in resources as the string for the database path passed to setDatabaseName doesn't get translated to the resource system so the database can't be found.

So where can I put it?  I don't want to just put it at the root of the drive like C:\repo.db or D:\repo.db as many people hate files cluttering their root directories (like me).  I was going to put it just in the source folder and access it as "repo.db" or as I tried "./resources/database/repo.db" but even QFile doesn't see that.  Where can I put it and how to access it there?  My settings file was going to be in my resources but I wasn't sure if I could update the file then.  I need a place that is available from the moment the application is installed on any system including my own so that it can be accessed both while coding it and when it's built.

I'm not asking for opinions - I want a place that is not in the root, somewhere universal like the installation directory (but how do I find that with code?) or a settings directory (but how do I set that somewhere so I can find it later??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such purposes Qt provides a list of `QStandardPaths` functions that return platform specific standard paths, such as a path to desktop, temp directory etc.
For your particular case you might put your database in the directory that corresponds to the `QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation` key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QSettings to save path,settings and restore them.

```
QSettings m_Arhive("Company", "app_name");
//Set DB path
m_Arhive.setValue("DBPath", "c:/somewhere/database");
//Get DB path
m_Arhive.value("DBPath").toString()
```